# FastReport OpenSource table cell borders spacing

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, fastreport

We want to use Table (TableObject) to show some data in our report, it works, but when we set it to show borders on cells there is a gap between cells that seems we cannot get rid of, tried this in a new report to verify we are not including something that cause the issue and even when the report designer preview shows it right when we open the web page is not showing in the same way.

We are using: ASP.NET core 3.1, FastReports.OpenSource.Web. 2020.2.9, FastReport Community Edition 2020.1.0.

Using print preview in report designer looks like this:

[image]

Running .net project and opening the report looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to remove space between cell borders to it looks like in preview?

Answer (score 0):

Found issue is being generated by the bootstrap css style box-sizing.

[image]